# how to pass headers in the reactJs code and get api results in console

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, axios, frontend

I have made a search button and written the code as given below but I need to pass headers that are given below but am unable to fetch results. is this way of passing headers correct or do I need to change something.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";


export default function App() {

 const [searchText ,setSearchText]=useState("");
  
  

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(searchText); ;
    }, [searchText]); 
    

  function searchForOrder(){
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `/api/orders-lookup/services/v4/orders?orderNo=${searchText}`,
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'WM_CONSUMER.ID': '2d0a30c7-b4cc-45d1-b451-d93535f5a92d', 
        'WM_CONSUMER.TENANT_ID': '0', 
        'WM_SVC.ENV': 'teflon', 
        'WM_SVC.NAME': 'order-service', 
        'WM_SVC.VERSION': '4.0.0', 
        'X-Request-ID': '1234_3bb32b5d-32e9-4d0a-ace6-e682edddd348', 
        'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID': '1234'
      }
    };
    
    //set up correct api call
   
    console.log(config)
    //handle api call
    
    axios.get(config)
    .then((response)=> {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }


  return (
    <div className='fullscreen-container'>
      <div className='Navbar'>
        <Navbar/>
      </div>
      <div className='template'>
        <div className='search'>
            <div className='form-control'>
              <label htmlFor='number'>Search your order Number</label>
              <input
                type='name'
                name='OrderNo'
                id='OrderNo'
                value={searchText}
                onChange={e => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
              />
              <button onClick={searchForOrder} className='submit'>search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My code is being successfully compiled but no result is being printed in console and giving me 404 error.

My error:

GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

I am stuck at here for 2 days if anyone can help me please do.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using config object then you would need to call axios directly not axios.get try the below code and check.

```
   function searchForOrder(){
        var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: `/api/orders-lookup/services/v4/orders?orderNo=${searchText}`, // Also I would recommend to use full URL or provide axios base url
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'WM_CONSUMER.ID': '2d0a30c7-b4cc-45d1-b451-d93535f5a92d', 
        'WM_CONSUMER.TENANT_ID': '0', 
        'WM_SVC.ENV': 'teflon', 
        'WM_SVC.NAME': 'order-service', 
        'WM_SVC.VERSION': '4.0.0', 
        'X-Request-ID': '1234_3bb32b5d-32e9-4d0a-ace6-e682edddd348', 
        'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID': '1234'
      }
    };
    
    //set up correct api call
   
    console.log(config)
    //handle api call
    
    axios(config) // earlier it was axios.get
    .then((response)=> {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```